# Rendering D3.js within an Ampersand.js app using Jade

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, pug, ampersand.js

This will be the first question I have asked on stackoverflow.  Please bear with me.

I am implementing an app using Ampersand.js as the framework and D3.js for visualizations.  The current state of the app is that it renders my ampersand-views (using Jade templates) correctly within an ampersand-page-switcher.  However, when I try to d3.select a div that I have declared in the template and draw something in an svg, I get no svg added to the page.

Interestingly when I do the same code from the Javascript console, it draws as expected.

Here is my map.jade template

```
section.page
  h3 Map Page
  div(class="mapholder")
```

Here is the D3 I am attempting to use

```
d3.select ('.mapholder')
  .append ("svg")
  .attr ("width", 400)
  .attr ("height", 400)
  .append ("circle")
  .style ("stroke", "gray")
  .style ("fill", "white")
  .attr ("r", 10)
  .attr ("cx", 300)
  .attr ("cy", 200);
```

I have tried changing the div to

```
div(id="mapholder")
```

and the D3 to

```
d3.select ('#mapholder')
```

https://github.com/benbenolson/NetFlow-Viewer/tree/master/src/test_app is the full source tree.  The template in questions is in /templates/pages/map.jade and the view is /client/view/map-view.js.  You'll have to find those yourself since I can't post more than 2 links.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having the same question using a handlebars template. Have you already discovered a solution? That would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `data-hook` attribute instead of an `id` or `class` attribute I have been able to solve this issue. So, in your template change replace `div(id="mapholder")` with `div(data-hook="mapholder")`. Furthermore, use the following `select` statement: `d3.select(this.queryByHook("#mapholder"))`

Summing up:

**Template**

```
div(data-hook="mapholder")
```

**Code**

```
d3.select(this.queryByHook("#mapholder"))`
```